# Getting error while testing react-navigation component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have created a component which is using `Provider` from `react-redux` and `NavigationContainer` from `react-navigation` but while testing it is throwing error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { NavigationContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createGlobalStore } from 'from somewhere';
import RootComponent from './RootComponent';

const middlewaresToApply = [];
const globalStore = createGlobalStore(middlewaresToApply);

class EntryComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={globalStore}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <RootComponent />
                </NavigationContainer>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default EntryComponent;
```

I have written snapshot test but getting error on this code.

'use strict';

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import EntryComponent from '../EntryComponent';

describe('Does EntryComponent render correctly', () => {
    it('When tested using snapshot.', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(<EntryComponent />).toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

When I remove `NavigationContainer` from component test works fine. How can I test component while using `NavigationContainer`.

Error -

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
  Check your code at EntryComponent.js:18.
      in EntryComponent (at EntryComponent.test.js:10)
console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9036
  The above error occurred in the <Context.Provider> component:
      in Provider (at EntryComponent.js:17)
      in EntryComponent (at EntryComponent.test.js:10)
  
  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

Comment: What's the error you get ?

Comment: @BloodyMonkey added the error log

Comment: It seems like you don't have set your screens. Navigation is made for navigating  between screens, but you don't have. Check the doc https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

Comment: yes screens are not added for navigation. But do you mean without setting that up my test case will fail?

Comment: I tested, it seems to works. Why are you creating EntryComponent like that ? it's really weird. Your error looks like EntryComponent return nothing. Can you post the code ?

Comment: Can you point out the issue with the implementation?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i was confused. So i don't know without more infos, maybe with a reproductible example i can help